# Get the value between the brackets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with some stuff that looks like the following string: `V2397(+60)`

How do I get the value between the brackets? In this case the `+60`.

The number (and character) before the brackets is not something standardized and neither the number between the brackets (it can be 100, 10 -10 or even 0...).

Comment: Expanded answer at [Get the value between the parentheses, multiple matches in one string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750701/get-the-value-between-the-parentheses-multiple-matches-in-one-string/34751380#34751380).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VBA code:

```
cellValue = "V2397(+60)"
openingParen = instr(cellValue, "(")
closingParen = instr(cellValue, ")")
enclosedValue = mid(cellValue, openingParen+1, closingParen-openingParen-1)
```

Obviously `cellValue` should be read from the cell.

Alternatively, if cell A1 has one of these values, then the following formula can be used to extrcat the enclosed value to a different cell:

```
=Mid(A1, Find("(", A1)+1, Find(")",A1)-Find("(",A1)-1)
```

Comment: +1 for showing both the VBA and the formula way of doing things

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I would use a regular expression for this as it easily handles

- a no match case
- multiple matches in one string if required
- more complex matches if your parsing needs evolve

The `Test` sub runs three sample string tests

The code below uses a UDF which you could call directly in Excel as well, ie `= GetParen(A10)`

```
Function GetParen(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim objRegMC As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "\((.+?)\)"
        If .Test(strIn) Then
            Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
            GetParen = objRegMC(0).submatches(0)
        Else
            GetParen = "No match"
        End If
    End With
    Set objRegex = Nothing
End Function

Sub Test()
MsgBox GetParen("V2397(+60)")
MsgBox GetParen("Not me")
MsgBox GetParen(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `InStr` to get the index of the open bracket character and of the close bracket character; then use `Mid` to retrieve the desired substring.

Using `InStr$` and `Mid$` will perform better, if the parameters are not variants.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andrew Cooper for his answer.

For anyone interested I refactored into a function...

```
 Private Function GetEnclosedValue(query As String, openingParen As String, closingParen As String) As String
    Dim pos1 As Long
    Dim pos2 As Long

    pos1 = InStr(query, openingParen)
    pos2 = InStr(query, closingParen)

    GetEnclosedValue = Mid(query, (pos1 + 1), (pos2 - pos1) - 1)
End Function
```

To use

```
value = GetEnclosedValue("V2397(+60)", "(", ")" )
```