# Excel extract from brackets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

The code from [Get the value between the brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058032/get-the-value-between-the-brackets) works well if the cell contains just one "(text)".

Unfortunately, in my rows there are many "Sample (sample1) (sample2)" format sentences and I need the last part.

```
Function GetParen(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "\((.+?)\)"
    If .Test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
        GetParen = objRegMC(0).submatches(0)
    Else
        GetParen = "No match"
    End If
End With
Set objRegex = Nothing
End Function
```

Could somebody help me to modify the code? Because if the cell contains "Text (text part1) (text part2)" The result what I get is "text part1" but I need the "text part2".
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with *regex* ?? Consider the alternative:

```
Public Function GetParen(strIn As String) As String
    Dim gather As Boolean, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim CH As String
    gather = False
    L = Len(strIn)
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        CH = Mid(strIn, i, 1)
        If gather Then GetParen = CH & GetParen
        If CH = ")" Then gather = True
        If CH = "(" Then Exit For
    Next i
    GetParen = Mid(GetParen, 2)
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Simpler:

```
Public Function GetParen2(strIn As String) As String
    ary = Split(strIn, "(")
    bry = Split(ary(UBound(ary)), ")")
    GetParen2 = bry(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Upvoted your alternative, Regexp beats the character by character loop hands down though for even this simple match.

Answer (score 1):

tiborjan:

I have a function that I wrote for just that reason. Here it is:

```
Function SubStr(s1 As String, sLeft As String, sL_Occ As Integer, sRight As String, sR_Occ As Integer) As String
'Cuts a piece of text from between two strings within another string
Dim LeftBound As Integer, RightBound As Integer, i As Integer

If sLeft = "Minimum" Then
    LeftBound = 0
Else
    For i = 1 To sL_Occ
        LeftBound = InStr(LeftBound + 1, s1, sLeft, vbTextCompare)
    Next i
End If

LeftBound = LeftBound + Len(sLeft) - 1  'measure from the right of the left bound

If sRight = "Maximum" Then
    RightBound = Len(s1) + 1
Else
    For i = 1 To sR_Occ
        RightBound = InStr(RightBound + 1, s1, sRight, vbTextCompare)
    Next i
End If

SubStr = Mid(s1, LeftBound + 1, RightBound - LeftBound - 1)
```

End Function

It has 5 parameters:

1. s1:  the string that contains the text you want to parse
2. sLeft:  the left-bound of the text you want to parse. Use "(" for your application.
3. sL_Occ:  iteration number of sLeft. So if you wanted the second "(" that appears in s1, make this 2.
4. sRight:  same as sLeft, but the right-bound.
5. sR_Occ:  same as sL_Occ, but referring to the right-bound.

To make it easy:  use this function code instead of yours. If you want to pull text from the second set of parentheses, use

s1 = "(P1) (P2) (P3) (P4)"

sLeft = "("

sL_Occ = 2

sRight = ")"

sR_Occ = 2

The return in the above would be "P2".

Hope that helps!
Matt, via ExcelArchitect.com

Answer (score 1):

or how about simply

```
Function LastParam(ByVal str As String) As String
Dim arr() As String

    arr = Split(str, "(")
    LastParam = Split(arr(UBound(arr, 1)), ")")(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you would only need minor changes to your code to make it work with your regex.

Set the Global flag to `True`, and return the last match from the match collection.

```
Function GetParen(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\((.+?)\)"
    If .Test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
        GetParen = objRegMC(objRegMC.Count - 1).submatches(0)
    Else
        GetParen = "No match"
    End If
End With
Set objRegex = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor tweak to my earlier `Regexp`will extract the last match.

*test*

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox GetParen("(Sample (sample1) (sample2)")
End Sub
```

*code*

```
Function GetParen(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "\((.+?)\)"
    .Global = True
    If .Test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
        GetParen = objRegMC(objRegMC.Count - 1).submatches(0)
    Else
        GetParen = "No match"
    End If
End With
Set objRegex = Nothing
End Function
```