# Get the value between the parentheses, multiple matches in one string

Tags: vba, excel

My spreadsheet has a column with value like this string:

```
some text (text1) some test (text2) (text1)
```

How do I get all values between parentheses? The result I am looking for is:

```
text1, text2
```

Even if `text1, text2... testn` is present in the cell multiple times, I need it in the result only once.

I found a function `GetParen` here: [Get the value between the brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058032/get-the-value-between-the-brackets)

It is helpful, but it gives the fist available value in the parentheses and ignores the rest.

Comment: To get multiple matches and not have duplicates, do you need the result in a single cell? If so this will require VBA.  If you are ok with the results being in multiple cells, this can be done with formulas.

Comment: The result has to be in one cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems unwieldy to have one User Defined Function for individual entries and another for a collective result of all entries.

Paste the following into a standard module code sheet.

```
Function getBracketedText(str As String, _
                 Optional pos As Integer = 0, _
                 Optional delim As String = ", ", _
                 Optional dupes As Boolean = False)
    Dim tmp As String, txt As String, a As Long, b As Long, p As Long, arr() As Variant

    tmp = str
    ReDim arr(1 To 1)

    For b = 1 To (Len(tmp) - Len(Replace(tmp, Chr(40), vbNullString)))
        p = InStr(p + 1, tmp, Chr(40))
        txt = Trim(Mid(tmp, p + 1, InStr(p + 1, tmp, Chr(41)) - (p + 1)))
        If UBound(Filter(arr, txt, True)) < 0 Or dupes Then   '<~~ check for duplicates within the array
            a = a + 1
            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To a)
            arr(UBound(arr)) = txt
        End If
    Next b

    If CBool(pos) Then
        getBracketedText = arr(pos)
    Else
        getBracketedText = Join(arr, delim)
    End If
End Function
```

Use like any other native worksheet function. There are optional parameters to retrieve an individual element or a collection as well as changing the default *<comma><space>* delimiter.

[image: bracket_text_no_duplicates]

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
Sub takingTheText()
Dim iniP 'first parenthesis
Dim endP 'last parentehis
Dim myText 'the text
Dim txtLen
Dim i
Dim tmp
Dim j
myText = Range("A1").Value

txtLen = Len(myText)
j = 0
Do 'Loop in the text
    i = i + 1 'a counter
    iniP = InStr(1, myText, "(", 1) 'found the first occurence of the (
    endP = InStr(1, myText, ")", 1) 'same as above

    tmp = tmp & Right(Left(myText, i), 1) 'take the text garbage text

    If i = iniP Then 'here comes the work
        j = j + 1 'here take the cell index
        myText = Replace(myText, tmp, "") 'remove the garbage text in front the first (
        tmp = Left(myText, endP - iniP - 1) 'reuse the var to store the usefull text
        Cells(1, 2).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value & Chr(10) & tmp 'store in the cell B1
        'If you want to stored in separated cells use the below code
        'Cells(j, 2).Value = tmp
        myText = Replace(myText, tmp & ")", "", 1, 1) ' remove the garbage text from the main text
        tmp = Empty 'empty the var
        i = 0 'reset the main counter
    End If
Loop While endP <> 0
```

End Sub

Result:

[image]

Please check and tellme if is ok.

Edit#1

`Cells(1, 2).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value & Chr(10) & tmp` this code store the text in separated lines inside the same cell, may be you want to use spaces between the resulting text because of `chr(10)` (also you can use `chr(13)`), then you can use `Cells(1, 2).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value & " " & tmp`, or use any other character instead the string inside the `&` symbols

Comment: ElbertV, please excuse my ignorance but i can't run the Sub you created. I  created a module with the Sub, when i type in the cell "=takingTheText(K7)" it returns an error: "The name you entered is not valid".

Comment: You need to run the code inside a Module, this is not a function, thats why you get an error. Inside the code you can change the the cell with the text, or if is a range of cell, you can take them and create a loop (do, for) to go across the cell.

Comment: May be, i can change the code to do a function for you... but i would need some time...

Comment: Thank you ElbertV, i appreciate it.

Comment: Good procedure. I might have made it responsive to the current selection. See [my take on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020?s=2|1.1545#28700020).