# VBA: Getting value/string between/in square brackets

Tags: excel, vba, instr

so I have found a great answer on here showing how to get the values or strings between brackets ([Get the value between the brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058032/get-the-value-between-the-brackets))
The code works perfectly, but when square brackets are involved, as in the following code, it gives me an error which I have been trying to fix for this whole day. I cannot seem to figure out what my problem is.
The error notification I get is: "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

```
For i = 6 To Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Columns.Count 

    kursName = Worksheets(FileName).Cells(1, i).Value

    klammerAuf = InStr(kursName, "[")
    klammerZu = InStr(kursName, "]")
    Cells(3, i) = Mid(kursName, klammerAuf + 1, klammerZu - klammerAuf - 1)
Next i
```

Comment: `Cells(1, i)` must have `]` otherwise `klammerZu` is zero and `klammerZu - klammerAuf - 1` will be negative. Wrap in `If klammerZu > klammerAuf ` Then/End If` block

Comment: `If InStr(kursName, "[") = 0 Then MsgBox "no []"` you don't need error handling, you need to test the result.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I might've found the solution. The selected cell didn't have a value with square brackets. The problem was that I didn't have any handling for errors. I'll leave this question for others who might run into the same error in the future.
Man, I feel dumb.
I'll take any propositions for error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function GetTextWithinBrackets(kursName As String, left As String, right As String)
    klammerAuf = InStr(kursName, left)
    klammerZu = InStr(klammerAuf + 1, kursName, right) ' start searching for the closing bracket after the opening one
    If klammerAuf * klammerZu Then ' check if both brackets were found
        GetTextWithinBrackets = Mid(kursName, klammerAuf + 1, klammerZu - klammerAuf - 1)
    Else
        GetTextWithinBrackets = "No " & left & " or " & right & " in the text"
    End If
End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print GetTextWithinBrackets("jkdsf]]]klsjc[=the text within brackets=]asd[[aw]]sd", "[", "]")
    Debug.Print GetTextWithinBrackets("872639281(=the text within brackets=)slsx(sladmlsa)", "(", ")")
    Debug.Print GetTextWithinBrackets("872639281=the text within brackets=]slsx(sladmlsa)", "[", "]")
End Sub
```

Outputs:

```
=the text within brackets=
=the text within brackets=
No [ or ] in the text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! I wonder if there is a way to get the last string within brackets? As I have Strings like this a (b) (c). The only condition I could think of is reading from right to left or always getting the last.